# Keeping track of pairs of Strings

Tags: java, dictionary

My current project requires me to utilize pairs of Strings for various use cases. I am currently using the Apache Lang3 Pair tuple to handle this case. The current implementation looks like the following

```
private List<Pair<String, String>> configParameters;
private List<Pair<String, String>> sensorReadingMeasures;
```

After discussion with the rest of the team it was decided that because we would need to expose these pairs of strings it would be best to find native Java solution.

I have attempted to find a solution using the AbstractMap in the java util library but I haven't had much luck being able to instantiate it, and a google search hasn't provided much information on helping me along.

I have attempted to recreate the above by doing,

```
AbstractMap<String, String> pair = new AbstractMap<String, String>();
```

I would be able to pull the required information using the keyset() function and pulling the needed information out by the get() function for each key value.

Beyond my instantiation problem this seems like a terribly inefficient way to get the same functionality, and I am curious if there is a better option. If there isn't can someone please provide an example on how to instantiate an AbstractMap appropriately.

Comment: Use `Map<String, String>` as reference, and instantiate - `HashMap<String, String>()`.

Comment: If you plan to use a `Map`, use it like `Map<String, String> pair = new HashMap<String, String>();` (or another `Map` implementation like `LinkedHashMap` or `TreeMap`). It would be better if you post the functional requirement to help you choose the best collection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If one of the two strings in each pair is unique, as your suggestion to use an `AbstractMap` seems to suggest, you may want to expose an API that returns `Map<String,String>`, and use an implementation of your choice for that interface (say, `LinkedHashMap<String,String>`).

The users of your class would be able to pull the pairs of `String`s from the `Map` by using `Map.Entry<String,String>`, rather than calling a `get` for each key:

```
Map<String,String> getAllPairs() {
    ...
}
...
for (Map.Entry<String,String> pair : myClass.getAllPairs()) {
    // You can use pair.getKey() and pair.getValue() here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you not just use a POJO:

```
public class Tuple {
    public String oneString;
    public String otherString;
}
```

You can have lists of them:

```
public List<Tuple> tuples = new ArrayList<Tuple>();
```

Or you can have `Collection`s of them that can be searched if you:

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        // Code to handle non-Tuples and null goes here
        // Code to handle null oneString values goes here (if you allow that)
        return ((Tuple)that).oneString.equals(oneString);
}

@Override
public int hashCode() {
        // handle null oneString values here
    return oneString.hashCode();
}
```